# Calculate distance between geopoints on parse with PHP

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com for my back-end, and in my table I have column named geopoint whose time type is `GeoPoint`. In another table I have the same. So I need to calculate distance between those two geopoints. Is there way to do that with parse? Or you can provide another solution. I'm using PHP

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [**How to Ask**](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We need more information - what have you tried? Where's your code?

Comment: Parse.com uses a NoSQL database (MongoDB). So it doesn't have tables but it has collections.

Comment: My code is on my server, not on CloudCode. I didn't write any code for distance because I don't have idea

Comment: The name of the formula you want is probably Great Circle Distance, Spherical Cosine Law, Haversine, or Vincenty. It involves lots of trignometric functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any code snippets it would be hard to give you the answer. I can point you in the right direction though.

As you are only using 2 points I assume you want Euclidean distance. (Straight line or 'as the crow flies')?

Wolfram has an excellent page on this here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Distance.html

It is (slightly) simplified here too: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/DistanceFormula.shtml

If you are still having trouble then post code snippets. Ideally something where you are already accessing these objects.